# Get column names with zero variance using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply

I'm trying to find any variables in my data that have zero variance (i.e. constant continuous variables).  I figured out how to do it with lapply but I would like to use dplyr as I'm trying to follow tidy data principles.  I can create a vector of just the variances using dplyr but its the last step where I find the values not equal to zero and return the variable names that confusing me.

Here's the code

```r
library(PReMiuM)
library(tidyverse)
#> ── Attaching packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse 1.2.1 ──
#> ✔ ggplot2 2.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.2.4
#> ✔ tibble  1.4.2     ✔ dplyr   0.7.4
#> ✔ tidyr   0.7.2     ✔ stringr 1.2.0
#> ✔ readr   1.2.0     ✔ forcats 0.2.0
#> ── Conflicts ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── tidyverse_conflicts() ──
#> ✖ dplyr::filter() masks stats::filter()
#> ✖ dplyr::lag()    masks stats::lag()


setwd("~/Stapleton_Lab/Projects/Premium/hybridAnalysis/")

# read in data from analysis script
df <- read_csv("./hybrid.csv")
#> Parsed with column specification:
#> cols(
#>   .default = col_double(),
#>   Exp = col_character(),
#>   Pedi = col_character(),
#>   Harvest = col_character()
#> )
#> See spec(...) for full column specifications.

# checking for missing variable
# df %>% 
#     select_if(function(x) any(is.na(x))) %>% 
    # summarise_all(funs(sum(is.na(.))))


# grab month for analysis
may <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==5)
june <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==6)
july <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==7)
aug <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==8)
sept <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==9)
oct <- df %>% 
    filter(Month==10)

# check for zero variance in continuous covariates
numericVars <- grep("Min|Max",names(june))

zero <- which(lapply(june[numericVars],var)==0,useNames = TRUE)

noVar <- june %>% 

    select(numericVars) %>% 

    summarise_all(var) %>% 

    filter_if(all, all_vars(. != 0))
#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical

#> Warning in .p(.tbl[[vars[[i]]]], ...): coercing argument of type 'double'
#> to logical
```

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. You refer to `hybrid.csv`, but we don't know its structure. Something we can work from and use to show you how to answer your question. Possible also a _desired outcome_ object to show exactly what you are aiming for.  I will also recommend to take a look at the [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Code that produces valid sample data inline would be useful instead of read_csv.

Comment: Will make it more clear in the future. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a reproducible example, I think what you are aiming for is below. Please note that as pointed out by Colin, I have not dealt with the issue of you selecting variables with a character variable.  See his answer for details on that.

```
# reproducible data
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$qsec <- 7

library(dplyr)

mtcars2 %>% 
  summarise_all(var) %>% 
  select_if(function(.) . == 0) %>% 
  names()
# [1] "mpg"  "qsec"
```

Personally, I think that obfuscates what you are doing.  One of the following using the `purrr` package (if you wish to remain in the tidyverse) would be my preference, with a well written comment.

```
library(purrr)

# Return a character vector of variable names which have 0 variance
names(mtcars2)[which(map_dbl(mtcars2, var) == 0)]
names(mtcars2)[map_lgl(mtcars2, function(x) var(x) == 0)]
```

If you'd like to optimize it for speed, stick with base R

```
# Return a character vector of variable names which have 0 variance
names(mtcars2)[vapply(mtcars2, function(x) var(x) == 0, logical(1))]
```

Comment: This answer should address him passing in a list of the column names as a variable.

Comment: You were correct about the speed.  It's hundredths of a second down to miliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems.

#### 1. Passing names of columns as a variable to `select()`

The vignette about that is here.  [programming with dplyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html).  The solution here is to use the `select_at()` scoped variant of the select function.

#### 2. Variance equals 0

```
noVar <- june %>% 
    select_at(.vars=numericVars) %>% 
    summarise_all(.funs=var) %>%
    filter_all(any_vars(. == 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

Select columns if unique count is 1 then get column names, using [@Benjamin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48425575) example data *mtcars2*:

```
mtcars2 %>% 
  select_if(function(.) n_distinct(.) == 1) %>% 
  names()
# [1] "mpg"  "qsec"
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers here are all good, but
as dplyr 1.0.0 deprecated the scoped variants (e.g. select_if, select_at, filter_all), here is an update using the same repex data given by @Benjamin:

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$mpg <- mtcars2$qsec <- 7

mtcars2 %>% 
  map_df( ~ var(.)) %>% 
  select(where( ~ . == 0))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 1 x 2
    mpg  qsec
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     0     0
```

or after `%>% names`:

```
[1] "mpg"  "qsec"
```