# Delete character vectors from df that contain the same string

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

I want to identify (and subsequently delete) character vectors from a dataset, that consist of entries, that are all equal (e.g. do not have any variation):

```
test_data <- tibble(a = c("A", "B", "C"), b = c("A", "A", "A"), c = c("", "", ""), d = 1:3)

test_data

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  a     b     c         d
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <dbl>
1 A     A     ""        1
2 B     A     ""        2
3 C     A     ""        3
```

I want the result to be something like this:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a         d
  <chr> <dbl>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 C         3
```

Of course I can achieve that by doing:

```
out <- c("b", "c")
test_data %>% select(- one_of((out)))
```

But as I have a lot of those columns and also a lot of rows, I'd prefer not to have to do it "manualy".

I found this [but it only works for numeric vectors.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48425289/get-column-names-with-zero-variance-using-dplyr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
test_data %>%
 select_if(~ !all(. == first(.)))

  a    
  <chr>
1 A    
2 B    
3 C
```

Or:

```
test_data %>%
 select_if(~ n_distinct(.) > 1)
```

Comment: The first one works, but I don't get, why...  I guessed, it would return only the first column, maybe You could explain, how this works?

Comment: it returns the columns where not all elements are the same as the first element.

Answer (score 2):

**Base R solution**

```
# (1)
test_data[sapply(test_data, function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1)]
```

```
# (2)
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, test_data)
```

**dplyr 1.0.0 solution**

```
test_data %>%
  select(where(~ n_distinct(.x) > 1))
```

---

**Output**

```
# # A tibble: 3 x 2
#   a         d
#   <chr> <int>
# 1 A         1
# 2 B         2
# 3 C         3
```

Answer (score 1):

you could also use `keep`:

```
test_data%>%
  keep(~length(unique(.))>1)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  a         d
  <chr> <int>
1 A         1
2 B         2
3 C         3
```

Answer (score 1):

A little late but you could also use `base::Filter()` to identify columns that contain only duplicates:

```
Filter(function(x) !all(duplicated(x)[-1L]), test_data)

# A tibble: 3 x 1
  a    
  <chr>
1 A    
2 B    
3 C
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `Filter` and `length` of `unique` elements in `base R`

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) > 1, test_data)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  a         d
#  <chr> <int>
#1 A         1
#2 B         2
#3 C         3
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
test_data %>% 
      select(where(~ length(unique(.)) > 1))
```